# Guess the Puzzling Stack Exchange User (Is it you?)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I really should be studying now, but:

> I am a user on Puzzling Stack Exchange.
>
> My name is sweet to eat.
>
> It is also chemistry-related.
>
> I think the Lion King is a pretty cool movie.
>
> My sister will never upvote or answer any of my questions...
>
> If you look at my profile, you'll see it is over 9,000.
>
> I LOVE anagrams!

Bonus points again if you can guess the sister...hehehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is

> QuantumTwinkie

My name is sweet to eat.

> Twinkie

It is also chemistry-related.

> Quantum, as in quantum mechanics. [Though that's more physics related IMO]

I think the Lion King is a pretty cool movie.

> The profile picture is [Bunga](https://lionking.wikia.com/wiki/Bunga) from the [Lion King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion_King) TV spin-off, [The Lion Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lion_Guard).

My sister will never upvote or answer any of my questions...

> Crozier says it's her

If you look at my profile, you'll see it is over 9,000.

> It's over 10k now...

I LOVE anagrams!

> And he loves solving my anagrams!

Comment: Wow, you guessed that fast! I thought I might have been too vague! I am the sister, lol.

Comment: @Crozier As soon as you mentioned sweet to eat, I knew it'd be him. Not to mention I too noticed that he went over 9000 recently.

Comment: Haha, good thinking!